# Check if particular object loaded in DOM using jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, dom

I don't want to know if an element contains a specific class, but just if it's loaded in *DOM*:

```
$(myObject).attr("class").length;
```

or

```
if($t.classList.length) {
     var classSUP = $t.attr("class");
   } else {
     var classSUP = $t.attr("id");
};
```

Comment: side note - your two var declarations will be hoisted and overwrite each other. you can't declare variables in a block in javascript.

Comment: @jbabey I'm sorry, what? All successive `var` prefixes after the first one are just ignored.

Comment: @jbabey Yes, the `var` declarations will be hoisted (one of them will result in creating the `classUP` variable, the other will be ignored, as @raina77ow noted). But the assignments are statements, not declarations and will not be hoisted. They will execute at that exact line of code where they are written.

Comment: @Imp yes thank you for clarifying. what i meant to say is that you should not write code that will be interpreted differently than you wrote it; it will lead to bugs in the future. you should declare variables outside of the condition and then just assign in the condition.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check would be:

```
if($("element").attr("class")) {
   return true;
}
```

Example shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/XpUJA/

Comment: @raina77ow I didn't know what OP wanted to do with it, so I just put `return true;` so that it could be replaced with whatever.

Comment: `hasAttr()` is not part of the standard jQuery API.

Comment: @jmoerdyk You're right, not sure how I've used that before then. Changed it so that it's correct.

Comment: thank's but i'm sure i have try this without results, maybe a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var containsClass = $t.attr("class") !== "" && $t.attr("class") !== undefined;
```

Here is as a function:

```
function containsClass($t)
{
     return $t.attr("class") !== "" && $t.attr("class") !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: More precise, `.attr('class')` will return `undefined` for these poor classless elements.

Comment: ... and for those that have their classes detached by `removeAttr`, too. But those suffering from `removeClass` will return an empty string in this case.

Comment: thank's a lot to everybody, it was very simple, i solve it by : if($t.attr('class') != undefined ){xxxxxxxx}

Comment: @gaelboyenval - As raina77ow said, elements who have their classes removed by `removeClass` will have a `class` attribute of an empty string, so it's safer to use my method because an empty string is not equal to undefined.

Comment: @jeff how to ask ? if(containsClass){} ? i don't know how to do

Comment: Do you want it as a function?

Comment: @jeff yes, but what is the value of a var like this ? Boolean ?

Comment: Yes, it will return a boolean. There it is as a function. I also edited both to make them more type-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Or how about just

```
(myObject.className != '')
```

or, just to be sure about possible additional spaces

```
(myObject.className.replace(' ', '') != '')
```

This is no job for a framework ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to do this:

```
if (element.className) {
    // element has a class
}
```

or, if you really want to use jQuery:

```
if ($('#elementID').attr('class')) {
    // element has a class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to detect if particular object loaded in DOM is:

```
if ( $('.className').length ) {
     alert('.className is on DOM')
}
```